# How can I know the checked/unckecked status of the checkboxes on the grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, checkbox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I've constructed a `DataGrid` by adding columns programatically using the following snippet:

```
var check = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox), "chkBxDetail");
dgDetalle.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn() { CellTemplate = 
                      new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = check } });
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
    dgDetalle.Columns.Add(textColumn);
}
```

How can I know the checked/unckecked status of the checkboxes on the grid?

**UPDATE**
I *can't* use binding

Comment: You bind a collection to the DataGrid and that boolean property is the  status of the checkbox.

Comment: @Blam I'm not using binding because the grid does not have a fixed set of columns...

Comment: That should not stop you from binding but I have tried to help you before and your typical response is that won't work.

Comment: @Blam I've not said it will not work. I simply *can't* because I'm doing code mainteinance and the `ItemsSource` is set to a `string[][]`, so to modify all the already written code could take more time than simply write the snippet to get the desired value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it...

I created the `DataGrid` using this snippet:

```
var check = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));

dgDetalle.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = check }
    });

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
    dgDetalle.Columns.Add(textColumn);
}
```

Then, I made a snippet to show data from selected items in a `MessageBox`:

```
string testValues = "";

for (int i = 0; i < dgDetalle.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgDetalle.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    FrameworkElement cellContent = dgDetalle.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row);
    CheckBox checkBox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cellContent, 0) as CheckBox;
    if (checkBox != null && (checkBox.IsChecked ?? false))
    {
        List<string> item = (List<string>)dgDetalle.Items[i];
        foreach (var t in item)
        {
            testValues += t;
        }
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(testValues);
```

To summarize:

1. Get the row using `ItemContainerGenerator`
2. Get the specific column from the `DataGrid` and take it as a generic presentation object (`FrameworkElement`)
3. Get the content using `VisualTreeHelper`. Notice that I got the `CheckBox` I've created on the first snippet
4. Process the selected item

Hope it helps anyone...!